# Cron job to check if PHP script is running

Tags: cron, php

I am having trouble regarding Cron jobs, I've basically got two PHP scripts that I want to keep running continuously on my server. Currently I am using an *infinte* loop to keep them going but they seem to stop at random times.

I'd ideally like to write a script that checks to see if the scripts are running and if they are not then to start them up.

I'm wondering how I might go about this?

Comment: How are you starting the script? You may need to use NOHUP or write an init script. Checkout 'fpm' for help on init scripts.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a daemon, not a cron job. [A cron job is for executing something *periodically* (or at boot), *not* for keeping a process alive.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_can_I_check_to_see_if_my_game_server_is_still_running.3F__I.27ll_put_a_script_in_crontab.2C_and_if_it.27s_not_running.2C_I.27ll_restart_it...) I encourage you to read that article, then do something very simple like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
   /my/script.php >> /var/log/my_script.log 2>&1
done
```

Answer (score -1):

To check for a runinng process you can list all the running processes (with ps) and then filter the one you're looking for with grep:

```
 ps aux | grep YOUR_PHP_COMMAND
```

If you want to start your command only when it's not running you can use the following script:

```
CMD="/bin/sleep 3" # replace it with your command
if ! ps x|grep -v grep|grep "$CMD"; then 
  $CMD
fi
```

NOTE: You need to use 'grep -v grep' to exclude the grep process from the process list.

If you want to put it in a CRON JOB you can pack it in one line with '**;**'

```
CMD="/bin/sleep 3"  ;  if ! ps aux|grep -v grep|grep "$CMD"; then $CMD  ;  fi
```

Remember that CRON JOBs are good for scheduling things. If you only want to keep a program running, a better approach will be an infinite loop which start the program whenever it ends.

Comment: Currently I am using an infinite loop - something like this: `nohup sh -c 'while true; do php get_tweets.php; done' >/dev/null &` it works fine but when I check in the morning it seems to have stopped.

Comment: I just read with my hosting service that if no http requests are recieved in 24 hours the system goes idle until the next http request, perhaps that explains why the scripts stop in the middle of the night

Comment: Ok, make sense. Then you need a script to make an http request at least once every 24 hours :)

Comment: -1 for a terrible solution to a [common problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_can_I_check_to_see_if_my_game_server_is_still_running.3F__I.27ll_put_a_script_in_crontab.2C_and_if_it.27s_not_running.2C_I.27ll_restart_it...).

Comment: Just read the question again,  and the last part of my answer...